# How to get a better export for a Laravel project using collections and the map function

Tags: excel, laravel, dictionary, collections

In my project, I'm exporting a sorted Collection to Excel, using the Maatwebsite/Excel functionality. It is working fine for the moment.

The result is a collection of cars with time worked on a car by means of different tasks. A car can have 1+ tasks/times.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Time;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;

class Times2Export implements FromCollection, WithMapping, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithColumnFormatting
{

    public function collection()
    {
        return Time::all()->sortBy("car_id");
    }

   public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Dossiernummer',            
            'Auto',
            'Taak',
            'Werknemer',
            'Starttijd',
            'Stoptijd',
            'Duur',
        ];
    }

    /**
    * @var Time $time
    */
    public function map($time): array
    {
       $dt = Carbon::parse($time->stop)->diffInSeconds(Carbon::parse($time->start));
        $duur = (is_null($time->stop)) ? 0 : $dt;

        return [
            $time->car->dossiernr,
            $time->car->brand . " " . $time->car->type . " (" . $time->car->license . ")",
            $time->task->name,
            $time->employee->name,
            $time->start,
            $time->stop,
            '=' . $duur . '/86400',
        ];

        return $time;
    }


    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'G' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4,
        ];
    }

}
```

My desire is that after each car I would like to have an empty line containing a COUNT of the time worked on the car, so counting the time in column G per car (based on x lines per car, where x is not known in advance).

I have been testing a lot, but I'm probably misunderstanding the map function (I'm still a beginner).

I was told that I should run over the collections, by using GroupBy - is that correct? I suppose like described in [this site](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html).

I have no idea where to start creating my collections. What can I try next?

### Update

Thanks very much for your effort and especially the optimization.

Let me try to show what I want to achieve.

Currently my output looks like this (I have blurred some items for user data reasons):

[image: original output]

This is how I would like to get it:

[image: Required output]

**UPDATE 15/04**

[image: Martin update]

Answer (score 1):

I never used that package, but based on the documentation, you should have your class like this:

```php
namespace App\Exports;

use App\Time;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;

class Times2Export implements FromCollection, WithMapping, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithColumnFormatting
{
    public function collection()
    {
        return Time::orderBy('car_id')->get();
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Dossiernummer',            
            'Auto',
            'Taak',
            'Werknemer',
            'Starttijd',
            'Stoptijd',
            'Duur',
        ];
    }

    public function map(Time $time): array
    {
        $duur = is_null($time->stop)
            ? 0
            : Carbon::parse($time->stop)->diffInSeconds(Carbon::parse($time->start));

        return [
            [
                $time->car->dossiernr,
                $time->car->brand . " " . $time->car->type . " (" . $time->car->license .     ")",
                $time->task->name,
                $time->employee->name,
                $time->start,
                $time->stop,
                '=' . $duur . '/86400',
            ],
            [
                $time
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'G' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME4,
        ];
    }
}
```

- See that I have changed `collection` method. If you do `Time::all()->sortBy('car_id')` it will order from 0 up but will first get the items from the DB and then sort it. If we do `Time::orderBy('car_id')->get()` we will get the data from the DB ordered ascendingly by `car_id` and then have it available as a `collection`. This takes way less time and memory, so always let the DB do this stuff.
- Then if you are doing `is_null($time->stop) ? 0 : XXXXXX`, do not calculate `XXXXXX` that is depending on `$time->stop` as it could cause problems, or worse, waste time calculating something that you will not use...
- And lastly, as the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/mapping.html#multiple-rows) says, if you want to return more than 1 row, you have to return an array of arrays, so each array (from the main array) is a row.

I think I still did not answer your question, I am not 100% sure if you want to show a car then time and another car and time again, or if you want to do something different (so please add an example as it is not clear).

Comment: Thanks Matias for your effort and the optimization. I have added info via Answer.

Comment: Let me ask you then, how do you know when to show the time ? What is the logic behind that ? How do you know how many cars after you have to show time ?

Comment: Hi Mattias, it is per car and license plate. So in the example image you see three lines that are the same car. Then one line of another car. 
In real life, this could be 20 cars off course. The GroupBy "car_id" is your group to know the total lines and total count.

Comment: I am reading the documentation and something looks like it is not following what my map function is. Are you using my map function (for the image you are showing us as the current behavior ?) I need you to show me what my function is actually returning because I think I have an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Matias, I took out the          
  [
           $time
   ],

part, because that returned the full collection in each line. 
My first image in updated version is how it is returned now.

Comment: PS I think I need to find a solution where each car (including all it's lines) is returned as a collection, calculation is made and then sent to the map function?

Comment: I need to see what my Map function was doing. If we see the first image (4 rows), was the time being inserted after each row or was it just outputting 1 row with the time after and nothing else ?

Comment: Matias, see update 15/04 with your map function in the question. Hope you're able to see (as quite small)/

Comment: Matias, see update 15/04 with your map function in the question. Hope you're able to see (as quite small)/

Comment: I see now... Your `map` function is more complex than it seems, I am not sure how to do it. You cannot use `group by` as it will remove data (instead of show each repetition).